# Showing Page Footer In Customer Account Statement

Tags: report, reporting, x++, microsoft-dynamics, ax

I can see this topic has been brought up before but not answered successfully.

I am wondering if it is actually possible to have a page footer showing on every page of the customer account statement, it is a very basic footer with 5 lines of static text, but I can see that the footers are printed as and when specific giro types are picked up by the report.

I have tried commenting all of this out and even removing all of the giro sections as we will never require these sections, but still the footer will not show.

I have also tried adding it to the existing code and using the Giro Type "None" as there is no Giro type specified, but I can see now the only way this will work is if the giro type "None" is specified which is also no use.

The only other way I can visualise this working is setting a programmable section and using element.goto"25000" but I do not know how this will actually work on every page as this is different from placing a section at the end of a report at a specific height.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In answer to my own question, I imported an existing copy of the report up to the stage before actually removing any Giro / Footer related.

I then searched through anything which disabled / enabled footers, removed anything Giro related and all of the Giro footers, after which my own footer was printed.